# Integer Input Controller for Multiple Inputs

Tags: jquery

I have the following code prevents user from entering non-integer values.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ResponseDays").keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8) { }
        else {
            if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Everything works great, but in a page I have many integer inputs and pasting this for many times makes my code look bad. How can I make this function work for many inputs, writing it only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give all the input you want to have this behaviour a class say `numeric` then attach the handler via the class.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".numeric").keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8) { }
        else {
            if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: you mean <input class="numeric" />?

Answer (score 0):

For the html:

Then the js
    $('input[type="tel"]').keydown(function (event) {....});

Then anything with the tel attribute will be just integers, and on mobile it will pull up the phone input instead of a full keyboard. On a phone now but replace the ellipsis with your keydown event obviously.